# Swift 4 insertTimeRange adds video tracks but when playing does not show except 1st one

Tags: ios, swift, video-processing

The following function "func mergeVideos()" reads video files prerecorded and makes a new movie file with tracks created with those files. dump(mixComposition.tracks  returns following for two video file tracks.

```
*▿ 2 elements
- <AVMutableCompositionTrack: 0x14661a30 trackID = 1, mediaType = vide,    editCount = 1> #0
 - super: AVCompositionTrack
  - super: AVAssetTrack
    - super: NSObject
- <AVMutableCompositionTrack: 0x14592bc0 trackID = 2, mediaType = vide, editCount = 1> #1
- super: AVCompositionTrack
  - super: AVAssetTrack
    - super: NSObject*
```

The problem is written, created new video's playing duration is as long as the first video duration. Insert time and duration time of added videos as follows and there is no problem with them.

```
▿ 2 elements
  - "1.mp4"
  - "video.mp4"

First video's insert and duration.
time= (0.0, 5.2316666666666665)
Second video's insert and duration.
time= (5.2316666666666665, 5.4366666666666665)
```

After hours of search we could not find similar problem so decided to ask.

```
func mergeVideos(){

    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition.init()
    var timeRange: CMTimeRange!
    var insertTime = kCMTimeZero



    for k in 0..<videoListOnDisk.count {

        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]).appendingPathComponent(videoListOnDisk[k])

        let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(url: url)

        let track = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video,
                                                preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))

        timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,videoAsset.duration ) 


        do {

            try track?.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0], at: insertTime) 

            } catch let error as NSError {

                print("error when adding video to mix = \(error)")

            }

       insertTime = CMTimeAdd(insertTime, videoAsset.duration)

    }



   dump(mixComposition.tracks)



    let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)

    exporter!.outputURL = fileURL(combinedVideoFileName)
    exporter!.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
    exporter!.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = false

    exporter!.exportAsynchronously() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

            print("I am done with exporting \(exporter?.status.rawValue)")

        })

    }     

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the repetition of this line:

```
let track = mixComposition.addMutableTrack...
```

Put that before the loop, so that you create only *one* video track and insert *all* the video clips into that *one* track.